# XML parsing in Python: how to get the string indexes of child nodes with regard to the flattened string

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, minidom

I'm a newcomer on XML parsing in Python and I need to obtain some data regarding the inner text of some phrase nodes and their children (preferably using Minidom, but it is not essential).

Example:

```
<phrase id="x.y">This example
    <foo id="x.y.z">
        <bar type="likelihood" ref="x.y.z">might</bar> 
    be useful</foo>.
</phrase>
```

What I want to get is the following data:

- The whole text in a string combining the parent node and their children (just like recursive method `getText`, which is featured in the Minidom documentation, does)
- A list of triplets containing children data:

  - tag name
  - start index considering the whole string
  - end index considering the whole string

In the xml example, `<bar>` inner text (*might*) starts at index 14 and ends at index 18, whereas `<foo>` contents (*be useful*) start at index 19 and end at index 28. The execution of this example should return something like that (the order of the children is of no importance):

`('This example might be useful.', [('bar', 14, 18), ('foo', 19, 28)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting project! Somewhat convoluted and not sure how far it will go with other situations, but try something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
phrase = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.fromstring(phrase)

#this requires a couple of help functions to clean up spaces, find indexes, etc.:

def space_rem(str):
    while '  ' in str:
        str = str.replace('  ', ' ')
    return str

def build(str):
    str_path = doc.xpath(f'//{str}/text()')
    str = ''
    for s in str_path:
        str+=(s.strip())
    space_rem(str)
    str_ind = ttxt.find(str)
    return str_ind,str_ind+len(str)

foo_lst = ['foo']
bar_lst = ['bar']
ttxt = ''

for t in doc.xpath('//*/text()'):
    ttxt+=t.replace('\n','')
ttxt = space_rem(ttxt)

foo_lst.extend(build('foo'))
bar_lst.extend(build('bar'))

ttxt,foo_lst,bar_lst
```

Output:

```
('This example might be useful.', ['foo', 19, 28], ['bar', 13, 18])
```